# Картинка заднего плана должна стать на передний план при поднесении мыши

Tags: javascript, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как правильно прописать код, чтобы при поднесении мыши, картинка заднего плана выдвигалась на передний (т.е. полностью была видна и не перекрыта другими картинками).
Вот мой код:

```
<style>
 .Top {
 position: relative; }

 .Base {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; }

 div.Picts {
position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto; 
        width: 400px;
    height: 300px; }
 
   .Pict:hover {
    z-index:3;
    cursor: pointer; }

</style>
                   ***
<div class='Top'>text</div>
<div class='Picts'>
<div class='Pict'><img src='///png'style='position: absolute;***; z-index:1>
<div class='Pict'><img src='///png'style='position: absolute;***; z-index:1>
<div class='Pict'><img src='///png'style='position: absolute;***; z-index:1>
<div class='Pict'><img src='///png'style='position: absolute;***; z-index:2>
</div>
<div class='Base'></div>
```

СПАСИБО!

Comment: Что за картинка заднего плана? При поднесении мышки куда и на сколько далеко?

Comment: Вам необходимо разобраться с перспективой. Вот свойство -  perspective https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective . По вашему коду совершенно не понятно как оно работает. Тут есть возможность задать код для примера.

Answer (score 0):

Желательно понятней описывать суть задачи, исходя из того что было обозначено я сделал то что смог понять.

```js
        const cards = document.querySelector('#cards');
        const dataImg = [
            { firstImg: 'http://surl.li/ljbbk', secondImg: 'http://surl.li/ljbbs', alt: 'imgName' },
            { firstImg: 'http://surl.li/ljbbk', secondImg: 'http://surl.li/ljbbs', alt: 'imgName' },
            { firstImg: 'http://surl.li/ljbbk', secondImg: 'http://surl.li/ljbbs', alt: 'imgName' },
        ]

        dataImg.forEach(element => {
            let card = document.createElement('div');
            card.classList.add('card');
            card.style.backgroundImage = `url(${element.firstImg})`;

            card.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
                card.style.backgroundImage = `url(${element.secondImg})`;
            });

            card.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
                card.style.backgroundImage = `url(${element.firstImg})`;
            });

            cards.append(card);
        });
```

```css
       .cards {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .card {
            height: 400px;
            width: 300px;
            margin: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-size: cover;
            transition: all 1s ease;
        }
```

```html
<div id="cards" class="cards"></div>
```

В этом коде ссылки на изображения храняться в массиве объектов, методом forEach перебираю эти ссылки, создаю элемент card в который вкладываю ссылки на картинки в качестве фона и с использованием событий JS mouseenter/mouseleave изображения меняються

Ссылка на GitHub Pages:
https://dmitriy-1986.github.io/cards-mouseenter-mouseleave-native-js/

Ссылка на репозиторий в GitHub:
https://github.com/Dmitriy-1986/cards-mouseenter-mouseleave-native-js

Comment: В таком случае хоть бы предзагрузку изображений делали, а то дёргано всё получается)

Comment: И к слову, лучше код заливать на codepen.io, куда удобнее будет. Да и тут сниппет пойдёт для такого кода.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь. В моем случае нужно было просто добавить position: absolute; чтобы сработал z-index:

```
.Pict:hover {
    z-index:3;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer; }
```